# How do I enable CkEditor for a textarea form element?

Tags: 6, forms, wysiwyg

I have a custom form and the following textarea element.

```php
$form['fieldset']['email_template'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textarea',
  '#title' => t('E-mail template content'),
  '#default_value' => '',    
  '#description' => t('A valid template for email trigger.<b>Please type ":" for variable suggestions</b>'),
  '#required' => TRUE,
  '#cols' => 60,
  '#resizable' => TRUE,
  '#rows' => 5,
);
```

After I installed the *CkEeditor* module and enabled it, the following text appeared under that form element.

> [image: screenshot]

I added *sky:notification/addTemplate.edit-email-template* in the *CkEditor* module settings as  element ID that should use the CkEditor, but the editor is still not used for that element.

How can I enable CkEditor for the *email_template* element?

Comment: this will help you https://www.drupal.org/node/1031160

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `'#wysiwyg' => TRUE` and use `'text_format'` for `'#type'`.

The form element definition would then be the following one, instead of the one you are using.

```php
$form['fieldset']['email_template'] = array(
  '#type' => 'text_format',
  '#wysiwyg' => TRUE,
  '#title' => t('E-mail template content'),
  '#default_value' => '',    
  '#description' => t('A valid template for email trigger.<b>Please type ":" for variable suggestions</b>'),
  '#required' => TRUE,
  '#cols' => 60,
  '#resizable' => TRUE,
  '#rows' => 5,
);
```

Comment: When i give '#type' => 'text_format' the textarea get disappearing

Answer (score 0):

You can just do that by adding `'#format' => 'filtered_html'` and `'#type' => 'text_format',`.

Comment: The question was about Drupal 6